# Playing an animation all the way through with one quick keypress with Mechanim Unity

Tags: c#, boolean, unity-game-engine

I have an if statement inside of the Update function that is only called if three other conditions are met. The problem is that right now the function sets a boolean to true which causes the animation to play inside of unity Mechanim. This boolean is only true when I hold down the button, but I would like it to play the whole animation or keep this boolean true for a certain amount of time, thanks and here is my Code.

```
//Running and jumping animation
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W) && (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space)) && otherAnimation == false) {
    anim.SetBool ("isRunningAndJumping", true);
} 
else {
    //anim.SetBool ("isRunningAndJumping", false);  
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if the behaviour is different if you get Input.GetKeyDown instead of Inpt.GetKey ?

Comment: Yes, when I did that the animation started playing when I pressed the key but stopped playing right after that. I want it to play through the whole animation when this happens.

Comment: The previous comment states what would happen with the bottom line uncommitted. The outcome of keeping that line as a comment would keep on playing the animation as the Boolean would stay true.

Comment: If you know how long the animation is, you can try `yield return new WaitForSeconds("animation time without quotes")`

Comment: How would I implement this into my code? Would I have to create another IENumerator function or something. Can you please show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this problem with the help of Kelv.Gonzales. I let the animation play for a set amount of time as I knew that it would last 0.9 seconds. This is the whole piece of code for this problem.

```
//Running and jumping animation
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W) && (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) && otherAnimation == false) {
        anim.SetBool ("isRunningAndJumping", true);
        StartCoroutine(WaitAndCallback(0.9f));
        //anim.SetBool ("isRunningAndJumping", false);
    } 
    else {
        //anim.SetBool ("isRunningAndJumping", false);  
    }

IEnumerator WaitAndCallback(float waitTime){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    anim.SetBool ("isRunningAndJumping", false);      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use StartCoroutine

```
//Running and jumping animation
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W) && (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space)) && otherAnimation == false) {
    anim.SetBool ("isRunningAndJumping", true);
    StartCoroutine(WaitAndCallback(animation["isRunningAndJumping"].length));
} 
else {
    //anim.SetBool ("isRunningAndJumping", false);  
}
```

Depends on your IEnumerator parameters?

```
IEnumerator WaitAndCallback(float waitTime){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);     
}
```

This is [where](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/407489/wait-for-a-animation-to-finish-in-unity3d.html) I got the sample code

Comment: And the 'gobool' represents what?

Comment: I was still trying to figure it out and I think its something relating to their own code where he creates a bool and checks it. I will tidy it up.

Comment: I got it. Sir, you deserve a cookie. Thanks so much! I'll post the code right here.